# Error Attempt to execute non-instruction

Tags: mips, qtspim

**My Input**

```
.text
.globl start


start:
# load with sign extension
lw $t0, memory
lh $t1, memory
lb $t2, memory


# load without sign extension
lhu $t3, memory
lbu $t4, memory

.data 
memory:
.word 0xABCDE080 # little endian: 80E0CDAB
```

**My Error**

> Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400028

[image: Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400028]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the CPU is trying to execute *data*.

Your program starts executing code at label `start`, it will execute all your load instructions and then you have not provided any code so the CPU will continue to execute what is stored after your last instruction which will be "data".

So after your last instruction you should either:

- issue a `jr $ra` to "return from a function" if you were writing a function
- issue a syscall 10 to terminate execution, i.e.:

  `li $v0, 10`

  `syscall`
- loop forever, i.e.:

  `loop: j loop`